# Typeahead Clearing My Text Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I am using the [Twitter Typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/README.md) on my web app. I make an Ajax call which populates my text box. When I click on that text box then click off (without changing anything) it clears the text box (setting the value to "").

Here is how I initialized my typeahead in the `(document).ready` function:

```
myTypeahead= $('#txtFoo').typeahead({
            name: 'Foo',
            valueKey: "Value",
            remote: '/ServiceHandler',
            template: ['<p>{{Value}}</p>'],
            engine: Hogan
        });
```

This only occurs when I don't change the value at all. Simply open the page with the Ajax loaded into the text box and click then off click.

Comment: Can you post a working example of your code?

Comment: You want the HTML? This is the working code for the typeahead, all I did was switch out variable names.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use `jQuery#val(val)` to set the value of the typeahead input, you need to use `jQuery#typeahead('setQuery', val)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the best answer for clearing typeahead.

$('#typeahead').typeahead('val', '');

//if you are using typeahead as an id.